# Entity Framework 6 or Core - Read query result with a "DataReader" like pattern

Tags: entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core, datareader

is there a way to get a LINQ query result on a EF DBContext as a 'Typed Data Reader', in sucha a way that when i am reading de IQueryable result (ex with a .ToList()) I don't put all the result in memory?

I am expecting something like this (or equivalent):

```
var personQueryResult=dbContext.People.Where(…).Select(…).AsDataReader();
foreach(person in personQueryResult){
   //Here I expect that person is typed of the People Dbset<T> type, ex. a Person type and i can do:

person.Name="...";
person.Surname="...";
//etc.
}
```

Comment: `DataReader` - no. But pulling the whole result set in memory via `ToList` is not mandatory - treating the query as `IEnumerable<T>` (eventually combined with `AsNoTracking`) and `foreach`-in it is pretty much an equivalent of "entity" `DataReader` because you read one item at the time.

Comment: Oh right! Foreach on `IEnumerable<T>` is definitely the right approch! Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not an explicit method that ensure you that that the collection would be scrolled trough a DbDataReader.

Knowing the inheritance hierarchy of the EF's base classes, every usage of a `foreach` on a `DbSet<T>,IQueryable<T>` or `IEnumerable<T>`, avoiding any direct method that will trigger a query deferred execution (ex. `ToList()`) will prevent to load all the records in memory so that at every "MoveNext()" of the enumerator will be used the "Read()" of the underlying `DbDataReader`.